# adding or substracting doubles gives wrong result

Tags: java, arrays, double, addition, operation

```
if (CIElchOpposite[2] < 180.0) {
    CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElchOpposite[2] + 180;
} else {
    CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElchOpposite[2] - 180;
}
```

For a given `CIElchOpposite[2] = 82;` the return result is `180` when it should be `262`.

`CIELchOpposite` is `double []`.

It should be really easy but no  matter what the operation is not done correctly.
This is the entire method, mapping a CIELab colour to CIELch space, calculating the opposite colour (just adding or substracting 180º) and then converting it back to CIELab. The mapping has been checked independently and works correctly.

```
double CIElch[] = MapFromCIElabtoCIElch
            .mapLabToLch(inputColorOneCIELAB);
    double CIElchOpposite[] = new double[3];
    CIElchOpposite[0] = CIElch[0];
    CIElchOpposite[1] = CIElch[1];

    if (CIElchOpposite[2] < 180.0) {
        CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElchOpposite[2] + 180;
    } else {
        CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElchOpposite[2] - 180;
    }

    double[] CIElabOpposite = new double[3];
    CIElabOpposite = MapFromCIElabtoCIElch.mapLchToLab(CIElchOpposite);
```

Comment: can you provide full code of this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CIElchOpposite[2]` is never assigned any value before the if statement

Perhaps you meant

```
if (CIElch[2] < 180.0) {
    CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElch[2] + 180;
} else {
    CIElchOpposite[2] = CIElch[2] - 180;
}
```

Note Java uses camelCase such as `cielchOpposite` and `cieLch`

Comment: u r right, sorry for the stupid question.....

Answer (score 0):

double is internally stored as a fraction in binary so values such as 0.123 cant be represented in binary format this is why you are getting wrong output from arithmetic

use BigDecimal instead 
`BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(b)`
do your asthmatics and then then return the value as double if you wish

```
bigDecimal.doubleValue()
```

aside from that `CIElchOpposite[2]` has never been assigned